# Create an empty element, in memory, in Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I just want to have an empty element using Cheerio. The use case is:

```
var $myElement = $(".myElementWhichExists")
...
doSomethingWith($myElement)
...
if (somethingHappens) {
    $myElement = $(".anotherElement")
} else {
    $myElement = null // This should not be null but an empty element instead
}
doSomethingElseWith($myElement)
// e.g.
$myElement.text()
```

What to replace `null` with so that methods like `.text()` will work (return an empty string or whatever), instead of throwing an error?

Is there a better solution than `$myElement = cheerio.load("")`?

Comment: Try `$('<span>')`

Comment: @marekful That will create a `<span>`, I want an arbitrary empty element—an object having all the methods of an element, but which is just empty.

Comment: You cannot have an "abstract" HTMLElement instance. You can only have instances of concrete subclasses of it. An empty span or div will not be visible in the document but can be added to it and it will satisfy your requirement to be able to call jQuery methods on it.

Comment: You can also create custom elements, check if this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements/Custom_Elements_with_Classes

Comment: It would help if you described exactly what you are trying to achieve. Chances are, you are taking the wrong approach. Had you shared the goal, we could help more easily.